# How to extract time from a column and subtract from a custom time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I would like to compare two time values.  The first time value is a custom time which reprsents the start time, for example the column name is Business_Start_time and set to 6:00:00 am.  I would also like to extract the time only from a column in Oracle which is a date field that looks like '5/1/2019 12:57:19 PM' and is called 'Completed_Date_Time'.  The purpose of this is to compare the businses start date to the time a file was completed.  I've tried to convert the 'Completed_Date_Time' field to 'HH24:MI:SS' format which seems to change the datatype to a char(8) value which does not allow me to compare two timestamps.

CAST(TO_CHAR(Completed_Date_Time, 'HH:MI:SS AM') AS CHAR(8))

Comment: What are those columns' datatypes? COMPLETED_DATE_TIME is DATE. What is BUSINESS_START_TIME?

Comment: The BUSINESS_START_TIME is a field I would need to create.  I assume it would need to be a timestamp since I'm only concerned with comparing the the time it takes each day to complete.  The COMPLETED_DATE_TIME is a DATE data type and Actual Type is Date Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the values to `TIMESTAMP` and then you can subtract the values from the values truncated to the start of the day to get an `INTERVAL` containing the time since midnight and to get the difference you can subtract.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Business_Start_time, Completed_Date_Time ) AS
  SELECT '6:00:00 AM',
         TO_DATE( '5/1/2019 12:57:19 PM', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
  FROM   DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ( completed_time - TRUNC( completed_time ) ) -
         ( start_time - TRUNC( start_time ) ) AS time_difference
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( business_start_time, 'HH12:MI:SS AM' ) AS start_time,
         CAST( Completed_Date_Time AS TIMESTAMP ) AS completed_time
  FROM   table_name
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | TIME_DIFFERENCE               |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | +000000000 06:57:19.000000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32e81c198c48119638486c7288b551b4)*

Answer (score 0):

Although you wrote both the question and a comment, I'm still not sure what you have and what you want to get. Sample case would help (create table & insert into).

Meanwhile, a few words about it: when subtracting two `DATE` datatype values, the result is number of **days**, which means that - if you want to display it in a format which is easier to read & understand - you have to do some calculations (a day has 24 hours; an hour has 60 mintues; and so forth).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (business_Start_time date,
  3     completed_date_Time date
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (business_start_time, completed_date_time) values
  2    (to_date('05.01.2019 12:57:19', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
  3     to_date('05.01.2019 18:58:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.
```

Simply subtracted, you'd get

```
SQL> select completed_date_time - business_start_time result from test;

    RESULT
----------
,250706019

SQL>
```

Here's a function which *presents* such a value in another format, `dd:hh:mi` (days:hours:minutes) (you can omit days by setting the second parameter to 0):

```
SQL> create or replace
  2     function f_days2ddhhmi (par_broj_dana in number, par_cb_dd in number)
  3        return varchar2
  4     is
  5        /*            Converting number of days into dd:hh:mi format
  6
  7                      Date from              Date to                  Diff (days)  Retval
  8                      --------------------   --------------------  --------------  ----------------------------------
  9                      20.11.2018. 07:00:00 - 20.11.2018. 13:45:00         0,28125  0:06:45 (6 hours 45 minutes)
 10                      23.10.2018. 07:00:00 - 25.10.2018. 22:12:00         2,63333  2:15:12 (2 daysa 15 hours 12 minutes)
 11
 12                      PAR_BROJ_DANA: 0.28125
 13                      PAR_CB_DD    : display number of days or not? 1 - yes --> 0:06:45
 14                                                                    0 - no  -->   06:45
 15        */
 16        l_broj_dana  number := round (par_broj_dana, 15); --  to avoid 1.99999999999999 days = 1 day 24 hours
 17        retval       varchar2 (20);
 18     begin
 19        with podaci
 20             as (select trunc (l_broj_dana) broj_dana,
 21                        round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24, 24), 2) broj_sati
 22                   from dual)
 23        select    decode (par_cb_dd,
 24                          1, lpad (p.broj_dana, 2, '0') || ':',
 25                          0, null)
 26               || lpad (trunc (p.broj_sati), 2, '0')
 27               || ':'
 28               || lpad (round ( (p.broj_sati - trunc (p.broj_sati)) * 60),
 29                        2,
 30                        '0')
 31          into retval
 32          from podaci p;
 33
 34        return retval;
 35     end f_days2ddhhmi;
 36  /

Function created.
```

Applied to the `test` table, you'd get

```
SQL> select f_days2ddhhmi(completed_date_time - business_start_time, 0) result
  2  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06:01
```

which means that the difference is 6 hours and 1 minute.

If that's what you asked, see whether you can use it. Feel free to enhance it to seconds etc. if necessary.